# This Code works VB but gives exception in VB.NET, Why?

Tags: .net, vb.net, excel, vb6-migration, vba

**Aim to achieve :**
I want to change the SourceData of the Pivot table.

I want to change it from `'C:\[file.xlsx]SheetName'!RangeName` to `'SheetName'!RangeName`

I have the following implementation :

```
For Each table In sheet.PivotTables
    Dim str = "'" + Split(table.SourceData, "]")(1)
    table.SourceData = str   // Gives Exception here
Next table

// Exception: Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC
```

At the time of error `str` has value `'SheetName'!RangeName` (This is fine.. )

I am also getting a message box before the exception :

`Can not open the source file C:\file.xlsx`  (Isn't that obvious because its in use)

Please help.. this works in VB as a Macro.

Comment: What is `str` at the time it errors?

Comment: Are you *just* changing the language? or are you making bigger changes, for example hosting it in ASP.NET (which isn't supported, btw).

Comment: I am talking about pivot tables in Excel, I am not using ASP.NET !

Comment: it had to be asked (we aren't psychic, and we don't know exactly what you are changing to/from). Basically, this *appears* to be something quirky at runtime - people are trying to help you find the appropriate set of quirks...

Comment: Another thing that cropped up - column count; any change the data (once pivoted) goes over 256 columns}?

Comment: Well, you can ask me the details, I can-not imagine on what you are working.

Comment: You say it works as a VB6 macro (in Excel) - is the .NET version also a macro in Excel? or is it something different? a standalone exe maybe?

Comment: .Net version is exe that i am making to process the excel file in visua studio 2010 express edition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the VB.Net version as if you would use it in an vb.net-exe. It will not work in EXCEL.VBA, but as I understand it you wanted a VB.Net version?

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop

Sub ChangePivotTableSourceData()
    Dim e As New Excel.Application
    e.Workbooks.Open("c:\testdoc.xlsx", , True) 'Open the doc readonly
    Dim sheet As Excel.Worksheet = e.ActiveSheet

    For Each table As Excel.PivotTable In sheet.PivotTables
        table.SourceData = "'" + Split(table.SourceData, "]")(1)
    Next

    e.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs("c:\testdoc_changed.xlsx") 'Save under another name
    e.ActiveWorkbook.Close()
    e.Quit()
    sheet = Nothing
    e = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: You did exactly what I did !
And your solution is also giving the same errors !

**Any one who wants to emulate can use this code.**

Comment: I dont use implicit declaration as you, and open the file readonly, and saving to another file. And using the Excel.Application. Your source does not tell us anything about how you open the file and so on. Thats why I made this answer. Now we know its not open in another excel.process as if used in vba or have bad close-routine. 

Can you please upload an example-file for us to test on. Then it's possible to give you 100% tested working solution. I have two questions, do you need the renameing of the document and is the document used by another process at the same time the function is called?

Comment: Well, I can't share my file publicly. No, the file is `not` used by any other process at the same time the function is called. Your code is almost what I did, except the read only mode and I am saving it to the same file and not to another file.

Comment: You cant create a dummy file with those pivottables in that we can test against?

Comment: I can arrange a dummy file with the pivottables.. I will post back here soon with the file.

Comment: Nice. Then we will crack this problem. :)

Answer (score 3):

*By suggestion of Marc Gravell, I change my comment into an answer:*

I can think of two reasons why your code breaks in VB.NET:

- If in VB you use somewhere in your code On Error Resume Next (oh horror), then you don't see it in VB, but will see it in VB.NET (because it doesn't allow errors to be ignored).
- You tagged Excel. I assume you went from an older version of Excel to a newer version or you moved your code from Excel to stand-alone VB.NET. A whole host of non VB-related changes might cause an error to popup.

Why you get an error about a printer not being available (or any of the other pointers Jon gave you), I don't know, but you might try that specific question on http://superuser.com.

Comment: (it has been noted that the error code can mean a range of different things, not *just* printers)

Comment: Nothing related to the printer !

Comment: @Yugal: I understand. But as has been said already, there are several causes for the error. But you asked _why_ it gives an exception in VB.NET and not in VB. I'd love to help you further if the above didn't help you enough.

Answer (score 1):

Supposedly, this error is to do with [no printer being available](http://bytes.com/topic/visual-basic-net/answers/513253-excel-interop-no-printers-installed-error). I don't know why you'd get it in VB.NET but not in VB... but you might want to look at your printer permissions etc.

EDIT: [This post](http://www.hagrin.com/319/exception-hresult-0x800a03ec-excel-net-sql-and-windows-server-2008) may be useful as well, showing DCOM service changes with regards to identity.

EDIT: Ooh, looks like the error can mean multiple things. [This MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6s0wczt9%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) mentions it in a regional settings context...

Comment: What printer ?

I am not trying to print anything, its about pivot tables.

Comment: If in VB you use somewhere in your code `On Error Resume Next` (oh horror), then you don't see it in VB, but will see it in VB.NET (because it doesn't allow errors to be ignored).

Comment: @Yugal: Sure, but goodness knows why bits of Office want printers :) All I'm saying is that that's what that HRESULT means.

Comment: @Yugal anything in the page header/footer related to this data? headers/footers are dependent on printers

Comment: Hm.. let me check once more .. !

Comment: @Yugal: See my edited answer - it could also be to do with DCOM service identities and/or regional settings...

Comment: Nothing related to the printers.. at all.. anywhere !

Comment: Yes, I read.. the links. I am using Windows XP 32 Bit.
I think it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Interop sucks basically. Check your processes (task manager) ... there should be at least one excel.exe process that isn't visible on the desktop. Kill them since they might have the file in use. That causes your 'Can not open the source file C:\file.xlsx' error. And who knows it might also fix your other error.

If it doesn't, check if you installed the latest interop assemblies and use those. It helps when you're dealing with Office products.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15s06t57(v=VS.100).aspx

Comment: Obviously, we are editing file.xlsx by our application, so there is an Excel.exe which is working with file.xlsx. SO What do I do ?

Comment: Excel isn't closed down properly when something goes wrong when using interop. So there is probably a process that's still running from a previous test/run that has the file opened and locked. So before you test/run make sure all excel instances are closed. During the execution it's normal though that there is a single process open.

Comment: I always make sure that there is no Excel.exe already running. So, that is not a problem.